# Why callback appears on jquery ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

On a test page i've got this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arreglo = [];
function parse_envivo(data) {
    if(data.length != 0) {
        alert(data.fuente);
        $.each(data, function(index, data) {
            if (jQuery.inArray(data.id, arreglo) == -1) {
                arreglo.push(data.id);
                $("#envivo > tbody:last").append("<tr><td>" + data.titulo + "</td><td>" + data.link + "</td><td>" + data.fuente + "</td></tr>");
            }
        });
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fecha = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            data: "fecha="+fecha,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "data.php",
            success: function(data){
                parse_envivo(data);
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

html

```
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="envivo">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Usuario</th>
                            <th>Acción</th>
                            <th>Título</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

working... but when i'm trying to move it into my website (with other jquery functions)

---

Hey! It was a jquery validation problem. After upgrading it to 1.8 problem solved :D

Thanks alL!

Comment: Is there any version difference between jquery used in both the environments?

Comment: How is the callback stoppping the script from working? If you don't want a callback, you need to make it asynchronous (which is harmful if you're requesting every 5s).

Comment: @Cybernate No, it's the same jquery!

Comment: @digitalFresh i dunno, for some reason the    success: function(data){
    parse_envivo(data);
   } it's not beeing called on whole site (on demo was)

Answer (score 0):

Try using POST instead of GET...

May be it will work for you..

Comment: I think it's the same... for some reason this
   success: function(data){
    parse_envivo(data);
   }
it's not working... and on demo was!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there is other js code calling `$.ajaxSetup()` ? I am wondering if there is some option set that you are unaware of... I have never used it, but I suspect `crossDomain: true` might have the affect you are seeing, as far as appending a callback function.

Comment: I'd search trought my whole functions.js and ajaxSetup it's never used.
You can take a look to my functions.js here http://jsfiddle.net/TugEa/1/

Comment: Not specifically yours, but any other javascript on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick-fix solution that I would be hesitant to use, but,

remove this line:

```
data: "fecha="+fecha,
```

and change this line

```
url: "data.php",
```

to

```
url: "data.php?fecha=" + fecha,
```

Comment: After changing it on console now it's 
http://www.website.net/envivo/data.php?fecha=1302791087&callback=jQuery1510014099772010502276_1302791084666&_=1302791097044
before was
http://www.website.net/envivo/data.php?callback=jQuery15104015414754286384_1302787907064&fecha=1302787909&_=1302788253868

but it's the same the success functinos it's not beeing called!

Thanks